# Soaking potatoes more than 24 hours

Tags: food-safety, potatoes

Is it okay to soak peeled potatoes in the fridge for more than 24 hours food safety-wise? It's only about 30 hours so far but everything I've read says they are okay up to 24 hours. (I didn't intend to soak them for that long).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

30 hours is fine. In most cases 24 hours just means prepare them the day before. I wouldn't eat them if they were soaking for 3 days. If you changed the water daily and they were refrigerated, they'd be safe but will have lost a lot of flavor.